# HMAC Javascript function has different result than the PHP

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash, encoding

I've got a javascript function that creates a Time Based One Time Password (TOTP).
Now I have to create that same TOTP at the server, using PHP.
I coded the same logic in PHP as in my javascript function.
For convenience, I created a javascript fiddle, and a PHP fiddle. So you can compare the codes and see the outputs.

**Javascript version:** (fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rrfk4ey9/1/)

```js
var TOTP = function() {
    var dec2hex = function(s) {
        return (s < 15.5 ? "0" : "") + Math.round(s).toString(16);
    };
    var hex2dec = function(s) {
        return parseInt(s, 16);
    };
    var leftpad = function(s, l, p) {
        if(l + 1 >= s.length) {
            s = Array(l + 1 - s.length).join(p) + s;
        }
        return s;
    };
 
    this.getOTP = function(secret) {
        try {
            var epoch = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
            
            // For testing, we take a fixed time. (same as in PHP version).
            var time = "0000000002f3e3c9";//leftpad(dec2hex(Math.floor(epoch / 30)), 16, "0");
            
            document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = secret;
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;
            
            var hmacObj = new jsSHA(time, "HEX");
            var hmac = hmacObj.getHMAC(secret, "TEXT", "SHA-1", "HEX");
            
            document.getElementById("hmac-out").innerHTML = hmac;
            
            var offset = hex2dec(hmac.substring(hmac.length - 1));
            var otp = (hex2dec(hmac.substr(offset * 2, 8)) & hex2dec("7fffffff")) + "";
            otp = (otp).substr(otp.length - 6, 6);
            
        } catch (error) {
     alert("Error: " + error);
            throw error;
        }
        
        return otp;
    };
 
};
var totpObj = new TOTP();
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = totpObj.getOTP("someSecret");
```

```css
output {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
#result {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsSHA/1.6.0/sha.js"></script>
<body>
<aside>This snippet uses external library <b>jsSHA</b> version <b>1.6.0</b></aside>
<hr />
<output>
  <div>Key:  <b id="key"></b></div>
  <div>Time: <b id="time"></b></div>
  <div>HMAC: <b id="hmac-out"></b></div>
  <div>code: <b id="result"></b></div>
</output>

</body>
```

**PHP version:** (http://ideone.com/s0Bwqu)

```
<?php
function leftPad($in, $len, $str) {

    return str_pad($in, $len, $str, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

$key = "someSecret";

$epoch = time();
// For testing, we take a fixed time. (same as in JS version).
$time = "0000000002f3e3c9";//leftPad(dechex(floor($epoch / 30)), 16, "0");
echo "Key:     " . $key . "\n";
echo "Time:    " . $time . "\n";

$hmac = hash_hmac("sha1", $time, $key, false);
echo "HMAC:    " . $hmac . "\n";

$offset = hexdec(substr($hmac, strlen($hmac) - 1));
$otp = (hexdec(substr($hmac, $offset * 2, 8)) & hexdec("7fffffff")) . "";
$otp = substr($otp, strlen($otp) - 6, 6);

echo "Code:    " . $otp . "\n";

?>
```

This yields:

```
Key:     someSecret
Time:    0000000002f3e3c9
HMAC:    5dcab54740bdca71e706c7e38a5c59fec3cb9c1a
Code:    094428
```

Note that in both versions (JS and PHP) the `time` and `key` are the same.
The `HMAC` differs, and so in my understanding here starts the problem.
The javascript version is the one I created first, and is proven to be working correctly.

I am pretty sure the problem is caused by the behavior of the jsSHA library.
So I put some things in perspective:

- jsSHA Library takes `time` in HEX format. Also in PHP the time is in HEX format when put in the `hash_hmac` function.
- `secret` (the `key`) is in TEXT format put in jsSHA. Also in PHP.

Actually, the point is getting the same result in PHP as the jsSHA library in javascript.
I'm sure I'm missing something. I have long been trying, and even Google does't know the answer.

Comment: Please post code directly in your question and not via third-party services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tell that jsSHA library that the input is a hexadecimal string here:

`var hmacObj = new jsSHA(time, "HEX");`

But you're not doing anything equivalent on the PHP side before/inside the `hash_hmac()` call. That means that jsSHA gets raw binary data, while PHP's `hash_hmac()` gets the literal string of "0000000002f3e3c9".
Naturally, that won't produce the same result.

Apply `hex2bin()` to `$time` before passing it to `hash_hmac()`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer. +1